# TFTP Server for multiple vlans

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, isc-dhcp, tftp

I have a linux dhcp/tftp server with multiple vlans serving a CMTS. The gist of it is in the CMTS, I tell the cable modems on what vlan I want them to get their address and configuration file from. The tftp server address is 192.168.130.2 and the vlan for the cable modems is on 10.0.115.2 (vlan115); where and how do I indicate that whatever device is coming in on vlan 115 go get their config file from 192.168.130.2?

I have verified communication between all vlans and that seems to be working ok. When the cable modems go through their ranging process they get stuck in a state that indicates a communication failure with the TFTP server which is why I'm wondering if I'm missing a step with the configuration. Thanks

Comment: Is 10.0.115.2 ip address on Linux server?

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy yes, here is how it is referenced in my dhcpd.conf file.

`}
shared-network eth0.115 {
 subnet 10.0.115.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 10.0.115.2;  
  option broadcast-address 10.0.115.255; 
  option bootfile-name "CM-BASIC-mib.cfg";
  filename "CM-BASIC-mib.cfg";
  pool {
    range 10.0.115.100 10.0.115.254;
  }
 }
}`

Comment: By default `tftpd` lists all interfaces on server. Use 10.0.115.2 as ip address of your tftp server.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy is it possible to set up multiple tftp addresses in the tftpd configuration?

Comment: Usually it configured by default to all. Or change ip in configuration to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy thanks, i'll give it a shot. The goal is to be able to have cable modems on any vlan connect to the one tftp to get its config file. thanks again,